# Something's up with my PPTP+SMB setup

Tags: samba, ubuntu-server, pptp

Yesterday I could connect to my PPTP VPN and access a SMB server on it perfectly well. Today it is throwing up a bucketload of problems. The VPN is now stopping internet traffic, even though it's set up to use the 192.168.2.x range, and I can no longer connect to the samba share, as the device appears to be invisible.
Both servers are running from the same machine running ubuntu server 14.04.

I need to know why this happened and how to stop it from happening again. It perplexes me to see that this worked yesterday and is so messed up today. Is there anything that can cause similar effects?

Comment: Have you connected to a network that is giving out a physical device IP in the same range as the VPN? (i.e. your Ethernet card is receiving 192.168.2.x IPs as well as your VPN). Can you ping the server when connected?

Comment: No, I'm running on the same Wi-Fi that I was yesterday, and I know it doesn't use that range. I've tested the server with 192.168.3.x range as well.